# MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots problem on ec2

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, redis, redis-cli

I`m using REDIS for data cache and I get error "MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled."  I google this problem and I "solve it" by creating "folder" for data  doing "CONFIG SET dir "/var/lib/redis""  and everything works fine, but after few hour this FOLDER disappear so I have to write ""CONFIG SET dir "/var/lib/redis"" again and its work...

I`m using AWS EC2 ( ubuntu)

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem